# django-registration-redux dont create the folder in my app

Tags: django, directory, registration, redux

Im trying to install django-registration-redux to my app and it work but I can't see where is the folder 'registration'.
It's really extrange, it work, but I need change the templates but I cant see where they are. Somebody can explain me where is the folder?

Comment: yes, i try to change every folder 'registration' from my others projects and nothing. thx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using virtualenv you can find it in 
`path_to_virtual_env/lib/pythonx.x/site-packages/registration`
or in `/usr/local/lib/pythonx.x/dist-packages/registration` if you are don't using virtualenv

Comment: Thank you, it take the views and the templates from C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\registration, what I can do for take it to my project?

Comment: I don't sure but I think if you simply copy it to your folder it will work

Comment: No, it didnt work, it still taking it from C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\registration

Comment: cut folder from C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\registration and paste it to your project folder

Comment: Then it dont find the url

Comment: Do you write url(r'^', include('registration.backends.default.urls')) in your root urls.py?

Comment: Yes, i have this: url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),

Comment: I don't know how you can fix this, you can change templates in folder with python libraries and don't move it to your project

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I solved this by cutting the folder from the `lib/site-packages/registration` and added the `registration` folder under `my-project` folder.

it will me something similar to this:

```
my-project
    app
    registration
```

Make sure that you have registration added in your `INSTALLED_APPS`

This suppose to work since you have your set `urls.py`